# Change XML root element name

Tags: c#

I have XML stored in string variable:

```
<ItemMasterList><ItemMaster><fpartno>xxx</fpartno><frev>000</frev><fac>Default</fac></ItemMaster></ItemMasterList>
```

Here I want to change XML tag `<ItemMasterList>` to `<Masterlist>`. How can I do this?

Comment: You should post a bit of the code you are using, as there is more than one way to do this.

Comment: + 1 for the question. I was going to bet a fortune that such question did not exist here. Very unusual scenario.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[System.Xml.XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and the associated classes in that same namespace will prove invaluable to you here.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(yourString);
XmlDocument docNew = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement newRoot = docNew.CreateElement("MasterList");
docNew.AppendChild(newRoot);
newRoot.InnerXml = doc.DocumentElement.InnerXml;
String xml = docNew.OuterXml;
```

Comment: Modified to include an example.

Comment: For a more general case you might want to worry about attributes on the root element, right?  `foreach (XmlAttribute attNode in doc.DocumentElement.Attributes) { newRoot.Attributes.Append((XmlAttribute)docNew.ImportNode(attNode, true)); }`

Answer (score 10):

I know i am a bit late, but just have to add this answer as no one seems to know about this.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<ItemMasterList><ItemMaster><fpartno>xxx</fpartno><frev>000</frev><fac>Default</fac></ItemMaster></ItemMasterList>");    
doc.Root.Name = "MasterList";
```

Which returns the following:

```
<MasterList>
  <ItemMaster>
    <fpartno>xxx</fpartno>
    <frev>000</frev>
    <fac>Default</fac>
  </ItemMaster>
</MasterList>
```

Comment: simpler, does exactly the rename, leaves everything else intact.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299195.aspx) to parse the XML string, create a new root and add the child elements and attributes of the original root to the new root:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<ItemMasterList>...</ItemMasterList>");

XDocument result = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Masterlist", doc.Root.Attributes(), doc.Root.Nodes()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `XmlDocument` way, you can do this as follows (and keep the tree intact):

```
XmlDocument oldDoc = new XmlDocument();
oldDoc.LoadXml("<ItemMasterList><ItemMaster><fpartno>xxx</fpartno><frev>000</frev><fac>Default</fac></ItemMaster></ItemMasterList>");
XmlNode node = oldDoc.SelectSingleNode("ItemMasterList");

XmlDocument newDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement ele = newDoc.CreateElement("MasterList");
ele.InnerXml = node.InnerXml;
```

If you now use `ele.OuterXml` is will return: (you you just need the string, otherwise use `XmlDocument.AppendChild(ele)` and you will be able to use the `XmlDocument` object some more)

```
<MasterList>
  <ItemMaster>
     <fpartno>xxx</fpartno>
     <frev>000</frev>
     <fac>Default</fac>
  </ItemMaster>
</MasterList>
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Will A, we can do it that way but for case where InnerXml equals the OuterXml the following solution will work out:

```
// Create a new Xml doc object with root node as "NewRootNode" and 
// copy the inner content from old doc object using the LastChild.
                    XmlDocument docNew = new XmlDocument();
                    XmlElement newRoot = docNew.CreateElement("NewRootNode");
                    docNew.AppendChild(newRoot);
// The below line solves the InnerXml equals the OuterXml Problem
                    newRoot.InnerXml = oldDoc.LastChild.InnerXml;
                    string xmlText = docNew.OuterXml;
```