# How to edit xml root name in stream?

Tags: c#, xml, stream

I get a webservice xml response like this:

```
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream1 = response.GetResponseStream();
```

This is the xml returned if I read `stream1` with a `TextReader`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataTable xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Cars" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Cars">
          ...
          ...
</DataTable>
```

I need to change the root element name: `<DataTable...` and `</DataTable>` to `DataTableCars`.  I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601211/change-xml-root-element-name) answer where it seems it can be done with `XmlDocument`.

However, can it be done in a simpler way in/only with the `Stream` and without having to create and modify it in a `XmlDocument` and then bring it back into a stream again for further use?

Comment: Why do you need to change?  Looks like you posted a schema and the actual xml file doesn't match the schema.  Maybe the error is in generating the xml and the xml doesn't meet the schema requirements.

Comment: I only consume the xml (and it's schema), and can't change that.  Various different datasets have that same root ("DataTable"), so I can't differentiate between them.  So I have to change the xml received's root name, so that I can deserialize with differentiated classes like "DataTableCars", "DataTableBikes".

Comment: You can deserialize with a different name using [XmlRoot("DataTableCars")]

Comment: I presume that line goes in my class I use to deserialize?  I do not understand however how that would work, because the deserialize process will still be receiving "DataTable" as the root ?

Comment: XML deserialize has a set of classes that match the name(s) of the xml tags.  Using XmlRoot says instead of using the class name for deserialize you can use a different name (the tagname in the xml file).

Comment: should I delete this question, since the solution was doing it a different way and not a direct answer to my question?

Comment: No.  Others may see this posting and get useful info from the comments.